# Электронная подпись

Tags: xml, java, soap

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь сгенерировать подпись к XML документу по ГОСТ34.10-2001, ипользую JCP криптопро.

```
Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(canon.canonicalize(outputStream2.toByteArray()));
byte[] bb = canon.canonicalize(outputStream2.toByteArray());
svt.setValue(sign("CryptoProSignature", key, bb));
```

Хранилище инициализирую так:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("FloppyStore");
ks.load(null, null);
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey("maiss", passwd.toCharArray());
```

Так вот, значение подписи получается каждый раз разное при одинаковых входных данных. В чём может быть проблема?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так и должно быть. При формировании ECC-подписи используется случайная точка на эллиптической кривой. Отсюда - недетерминированный результат.

[Алгоритм](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Forming_of_sign_gost_P34.10-2001.png/480px-Forming_of_sign_gost_P34.10-2001.png)

Comment: Вот уж не знал, что для подписи может использоваться ГСЧ

Comment: Почему? Это ведь как раз повышает надежность.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем канонизировать XML? Может он сволочь вставляет где-то тайстамп канонизации XML? Иначе действительно трудно объяснить.

Сделайте так:
1) проверьте вход перед подачей на подпись - отличается ли от прогона к прогону
2) попробуйте другой алгоритм подписи - работает нет? Сдается мне ГОСТ тут не причем

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Без канонизации тот же результат, вход проверял, одинаковый. Пытался даже прогонять, подставляя на вход `"a".getBytes()`, генерируется, опять-таки разный выход.
У меня осталось два варианта: 

1. Где-то в алгоритме используется время или гсч 
2. Вместо закрытого ключа из контейнера читается что-то не то